# PHP Scope? Or Codeigniter? Both? Neither (my own stupidity?)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

So, I am new to Codeigniter.  I've set up a model class to handle user authorization, both for storing tokens in the db and an index in a cookie.  I set up a cookie as a property of the class but can't seem to get it to store.  This is one of those problems that is most likely stupidity on my part (see title) but I'm at a loss.  Here's the relevant code:

```
class Auth_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Include files from google-php-client library
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php";
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php";
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";
    }

    var $mm_cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'ID',
        'value'  => '',
        'expire' => '86500',
        'domain' => '',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => 'pref',
        'secure' => TRUE
    );

    public function setUserData ($p_aUserData) {
        log_message("debug", "GET vars:" . print_r($_GET,true));

        // Check for existing service ID
        if( isset($p_aUserData['id']) ) {           // Check the 'id'
            $SQL = "SELECT ID FROM tbl_user WHERE tbl_user.id = " . $p_aUserData['id'];
            $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
            $result = $query->result();

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $this->mm_cookie['value'] = $p_aUserData->ID;

               ...  

                $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (" [my columns] ") VALUES (" . $valueString . ")";
                $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
                if( !$query ) $retArray = array( 'status' => 'error', 'info' => array('message' => $this->db->_error_message(), 'code' => $this->db->_error_number(), 'SQL' => $SQL ) );
                else {
                    $lastInsertID = $this->db->insert_id();
                    $this->mm_cookie['value'] = $lastInsertID;
                    $retArray = array( 'status' => 'success', 'info' => array('message' => "INSERT successful", 'lastInsertID' => $lastInsertID, 'SQL' => $SQL ) );
                }
            }

== 1 ==>    log_message("debug", "Cookie Storing AUTH_MODEL: " . print_r($this->mm_cookie, true));</b>

            $this->input->set_cookie($this->mm_cookie);
        } else {
            $retArray = array( 'status' => 'error', 'info' => array('message' => "No Service ID specified") );
        }
        return $retArray;
    }
}
```

I've used this basic pattern before with other languages, including PHP (just not CI). Either I'm making a boneheaded mistake that I'm not seeing or something is wacky with CI.  I am new to PHP namespaces but I don't see how that would affect this.

Sorry for the additional cruft but I wanted to show everything in case there is something I messed up.

At my mark in the code of "== 1 ==>" the `$this->mm_cookie` array displays just as I would expect.  The next line never results in a cookie.  It seems that if I do not make it a property of the class, it works.  I've set it as both a public and private property.

I'd like to know why it doesn't work as a property and if I've done something principally wrong that will reveal itself more significantly later in the process.

Scott.

Comment: You're asking why `$this->input->set_cookie(...)` doesn't set your array even though when printed, it clearly shows right data? It could be anything: your browser blocks cookies, it's CodeIgniter's bug, you misconfigured CI, you printed something before so that headers can't be changed... etc.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking why the the array that is a class property is not being set as a cookie.  Unless that is what you meant.  Your response is in essence repeating my question.  My browser does not block cookies.  The CI session cookie is being set just fine.  Misconfiguring CI is certainly a possibility but this is the only place it's acting weird.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies is not set because you not include cookie helper in your constructor

```
 public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('cookie');
            // Include files from google-php-client library
            include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php";
            include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php";
            include_once APPPATH . "libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";
}
```

And read manual [Cookie Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

Comment: Actually, I did load the cookie helper in the controller.  Good catch, though.  So, what *IS* the best place for that stuff?  Controller?  Model?  Autoloader?

Comment: If you place this in auto load file it will include in all controller and if you include it in controller constructer it will include only for that controller

Comment: Thanks for the best practice.  I now have added it into the autoload.php.  Still not storing the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookies very often it is best to load in in your `autoload.php` file itself in the config folder.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie');
```

**EDIT**

Why dont you create that cookie variable inside the function `setUserData ($p_aUserData)` ?

**NOTE**
Remove the `var` from the declaration

```
 $mm_cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'ID',
        'value'  => '',
        'expire' => '86500',
        'domain' => '',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => 'pref',
        'secure' => TRUE
    );
```

and then you can directly use the varibale like

```
$this->input->set_cookie($mm_cookie);
```

from inside the function `setUserData();`

The `var` declaration will only work for the PHP version from 5.0.0 up to version 5.1.2. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Added that into autoload.php.  Still no joy.

Comment: Can you update your code? the recent changes that you have made after the suggestions?

Comment: Running 5.6.7.  I tried making it local to setUserData() method already with no luck.  And the mods I made really just added the helper into autoload.php:

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'cookie', 'date');`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you don't seem to load the cookie helper from CodeIgniter.  The documentation for cookies in [CI2](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/cookie_helper.html) and [CI3](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html) show that you need to load the helper by doing:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

I am assuming you aren't autoloading the helper though.